# How to use nested queries for dynamoDB using AWS CLI

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I'm trying to delete some items in dynamodb which currently is not null.I'm not sure how many items will be there.So first I've used a scan with filter attributes to get that item then I'll feed that result set to delete-item

So far I can able to perform the first step. but I couldn't figure out how the nested queries may work with dynamodb (Using AWS CLI)

**filter.json**

```
{
  "demo": {
    "ComparisonOperator": "NOT_NULL"
  }
}
```

**First Query:**

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --scan-filter file://D:\filter.JSON
```

Now I need to find a way to  feed the result set of the above query into [delete-item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/delete-item.html)

> **UPDATE 1**

**Output of Scanned query:**

```
{
    "Count": 2,
    "Items": [
        {
            "demo": {
                "S": "Hai"
            },            
            "id": {
                "S": "123"
            }
        },
        {            
            "demo": {
                "S": "Welcome"
            },
            "id": {
                "S": "124"
            }

        }
    ],
    "ScannedCount": 3643,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

Comment: Can you share the redacted response of the `scan` command's output?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR Please see the **UPDATE 1**

Comment: Can you try this: `for item in $(aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --query 'Items[*]. id.S' --output text) ; do aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name test --key $item; done`? This command assumes that `id` is the primary key. If it is demo, please change the command.